# How to reverse the input string

Tags: python

If this is the input:

`This is an example line of text.`

Then how can I get this output:

`.txet fo enil elpmaxe na si sihT`

Comment: Please try to put more efforts on research before you ask a question here. If you try and fail, post your attempts and explain where you're stuck and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

```
def my_function(x):
  return x[::-1]

mytxt = my_function("I wonder how this text looks like backwards")

print(mytxt)
```